# Constraints on sum of rows and columns of matrix

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, matrices

Suppose $r_i$, $1 \le i \le n$, and $c_j$, $1 \le j \le m$, are nonnegative integers.  When does there exist an $n \times m$ matrix in $\text{Mat}_{n \times m} (\mathbb{Z}^+)$, i.e. nonnegative entries, such that $r_i$ is the sum of the entries in its $i$th row and $c_j$ is the sum of the entries in its $j$th columns?

Comment: @user314: Why the algebra-precalculus tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-negative integer solutions exist whenever the (also necessary) "balance condition" is met:

$$ \sum_i r_i = \sum_j c_j $$

which simply sums the total matrix entries in two ways.

There is a survey paper by Alexander Barvinok on this:
http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/linalg.pdf

Comment: Yes, it's a very active area. One of my fellow graduate students is working on this for his thesis.