# Given two non-negative vectors $r,c$, is there always a non-negative matrix A whose marginals are $r$ and $c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $A$ be an nxm matrix.
We can easily determine its row and column marginals $r$ and $c$:
$r=A1$
$c=1^TA$.

Suppose however, that you are given **non-negative** marginals $r,c$.
Is there always a **non-negative** matrix $A$ whose marginals are $r$ and $c$ (obviously $r^T1 = 1^Tc$)?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Have you come up with any approaches to this question?  Are you expecting the answer to be well known?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom. I believe there should always be such a matrix A.  
Intuitively, for large enough A, the marginals induce an underdetermined system of linear equations. The only problem is the non-negativity.

I suspect the result is known, or is implied by some other work on non-negative matrices. An approach I believe should work is using Farkas' Lemma. But, maybe there are simpler approaches...

Comment: A similar question (see below) addresses the case where A has to have integer values. I am not interested in this special case, but the more general case.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315959/finding-all-possible-n-times-n-matrices-with-non-negative-entries-and-given-ro