A sum related to multinomials
Let $x_{ij}$ be a matrix of non-negative integers, with $i\in\{1,\dots,N\}$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,M\}$. I need to evaluate the following sum:
$$
\sum_{\{x_{ij}\}} \frac{\prod_{j}\left( \sum_{i}x_{ij} \right)!}{\prod_{ij}x_{ij}!} \prod_{i}\delta\left( \sum_{j}x_{ij}-c_{i} \right)
$$
where the $c_i$ are given non-negative integers and $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Kronecker delta. Can we evaluate this in closed-form, or simplify it somehow?
Relation to multinomials.
The difficulty stems from the presence of the factorials $\left( \sum_{i}x_{ij} \right)!$ in the numerator of the summand. Indeed, if these terms were not present, the sum can be carried out with the Multinomial Theorem,
$$
\sum_{\{x_{ij}\}} \frac{1}{\prod_{ij}x_{ij}!} \prod_{i}\delta\left( \sum_{j}x_{ij}-X_{i} \right) = \prod_i\sum_{\{x_{ij}\}} \frac{\delta\left( \sum_{j}x_{ij}-X_{i} \right)}{\prod_{j}x_{ij}!} = \prod_i \frac{M^{X_i}}{X_i!}
$$

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428671/simplify-sum-x-ij-forall-i-sum-j-x-ij-xi-i-forall-j-sum-i-x-i

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5002827/evaluate-sum-x-ij-frac1-prod-ijx-ij-prod-i-delta-sum-j
