Evaluate $\sum_{\{x_{ij}\}} \frac{1}{\prod_{ij}x_{ij}!}[\prod_{i}\delta(\sum_{j}x_{ij};a_{i})][\prod_{j}\delta(\sum_{i}x_{ij};b_{j})]$
Let $x_{ij}$ be a matrix of non-negative integers, with $i \in \left\{1,\dots,N\right\}$ $\mbox{and}\ j \in \left\{1,\dots,M\right\}$.

I need to evaluate the following sum:
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{S}\left({\bf a},{\bf b}\right)
\\ = & \
\sum_{\{x_{ij}\}} \frac{1}{\prod_{ij}x_{ij}!} 
\left[\prod_{i}\delta\left(\sum_{j}x_{ij};a_{i} \right)\right]
\left[\prod_{j}\delta\left( \sum_{i}x_{ij};b_{j} \right)\right]
\end{align}
$$
\mbox{where the}\quad
\mathbf{a} = \left(a_{i}\right)_{i = 1}^{N}\quad \mbox{and}\quad \mathbf{b} = \left(b_{j}\right)_{j = 1}^{M}
$$
are given non-negative integers, and $\delta(x;y)$ is the Kronecker symbol.
Note that $\sum_{i}a_{i} = \sum_{j}b_{j}$ should be equal or no matrix can satisfy both sets of constraints.
Can we evaluate this in closed-form, or simplify it somehow ?.

Relation to multinomials:
The difficulty seems to stem from the presence of the constraints acting on both rows and columns of the matrix $x_{ij}$.

If we considered instead a vector $x_{i}$, the sum:
$$
\sum_{\left\{x_{i}\right\}}
\frac{1}{\prod_{i}x_{i}!}
\delta\left(\sum_{i}x_{i} - a\right) = \frac{N^{a}}{a!}
$$
is easily evaluated by the multinomial theorem.

